# How to reload local JSON schema in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsonschema

I'm developing a JSON schema and referenced it for tests in another project.

When I edit the JSON schema, changes are not applied until I reload the window in other project.

Answer (score 3):

Go into File > Preferences > Settings, search for JSON and find the following setting:
JSON > Schema Download: Enable

If you toggle that off and on VS Code will grab the latest version of the schema files.

Comment: For people who wants to edit **settings.json** directly, just add `"json.schemaDownload.enable": false`

Answer (score 0):

Very quick workaround to force vs code to reload the file: add a dummy parameter at the end of the schema url, e.g.

```json
{"$schema": "file:///home/user/foo.json"}
```

becomes

```json
{"$schema": "file:///home/user/foo.json?dummy=1"}
```

For yaml files:

```yaml
# yaml-language-server: $schema=file:///home/user/foo.json?dummy=1
```